# How to keep ViewController details the same after going to another tab in Tab Bar Controller Swift

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uitabbarcontroller

I am having trouble with my Tab Bar Controller. On tab 1 I have a map. The map is on auto layout to fill approximately half of the screen. I have an option to make the map full screen. If I were to make the map full screen, go to tab 2 and return to tab 1, the map will be back in its auto layout position. In this case, I would need it to be full screen.

Any ideas on how to overcome this problem?

Comment: I'd use NSUserDefaults to store the size of a map a retrieve it anytime the view is about to appear

Comment: I actually tried storing the map size in a singleton before leaving the view. When I came back the map would get to the correct size, but you could notice that the map was sorta glitchy. So I wanted to avoid this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I repro'ed your case, and I could see the glitch part when trying to call the function from viewDidAppear. However when I put the logic in viewDidLayoutSubviews, it was pretty smooth. The following is the code that I tried:

```
@IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("isMapFullScreen")) {
        self.map.frame = self.view.bounds;
    }
}

@IBAction func buttonIsClicked(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.map.frame = self.view.bounds;
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "isMapFullScreen")
}
```

Comment: Thanks Guy! Worked like a charm. Thanks for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is save the user preference using:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "isMapFullScreen")
```

And then in the ViewWillAppear, just do:

```
if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("isMapFullScreen")) {
     // Put map on full screen
}
```

Comment: I actually tried storing the map size in a singleton before leaving the view. When I came back the map would get to the correct size, but you could notice that the map was sorta glitchy. So I wanted to avoid this. Any ideas?

Comment: Ohh I see what you mean. I am not in front of my mac now, but I can try it later and get back to you.

Comment: Great Thank you! I appreciate the help!